# How to make ansi c function programmable for non-programmers using simple if-then-else-clauses?

Tags: c, ansi-c

I have a software for home automation written in ansi C, running on ARM Cortex M4. Now, I'd like to let regulation part to be programmed by my friend, that knows regulations well, but is not C or any other language programmer.

My current plan is to hide details from him as much as possible, so he can concentrate on program logic and flow.

Instead of this :

```
   if (struct1.struct2.struct3.temperature_of_room < 20) struct1.struct2.out = 1;
```

I let him use this :

```
   if (T_ROOM) OUTPUT(HEAT,ON)
```

and then say

```
   #define T_ROOM  struct1.struct2.struct3.temperature_of_room and similar...
```

I'm willing to do this for all other data he will use I'd also like some sort of debugging (with printf) to this scheme and some other usefull concepts...

I wonder if there are any better or more efficient ways to do this ? Any other pointers? I bet someone has also done this, but I can't find anything usefull on search engines...

Thanks in advance,

regards,
Bul.

Comment: By the way - this is called a "DSL" (Domain Specific Language). Maybe try googling for that.

Comment: Aye DSL, it's a huge and interesting topic. Even more useful you could  could write a DSL to take a description you both understand e.g Keep room warm, and have it generate the C code. I wouldn't even attempt to write anything beyond the most trivial DSL in C, Dynamic and as I understand Functional languages can do it much better.

Answer (score 1):

This tends to be a bad idea. You're not the first one to come up with the idea of "a simplified language for non-programmers". The problem is, you invariably end up with another programming language anyway. Except yours will be a lot buggier and awkward than the ones already existing.

The better approach is either to get the requirements from him and then write the code yourself, or use a [visual programming language like this](http://code.google.com/p/blockly/). Though if it's on an embedded ARM device, that might not be an option.

Comment: I won't go deep in here... Just hide input variables and outputs. And then use only simple if-then-else with possibility of goto (cause they are deeply nested) and that's ok. Nothing more for now. I'f I'm honest it looks more informative for me also...

Comment: @user2152780 - Well, you can try, of course. Though be prepared that his code will be spaghetti-like and barely maintainable. Also, if it's deeply nested, that means very many branches and exceptions. We programmers are trained to think about every possible case and make a big picture of it all. Non-programmers are not. It'll be very easy for him to make a mistake.

Comment: @user2152780 - Then again, it is possible to do [this](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/_0x23_include__0x22_pascal_0x2e_h_0x22_.aspx), so...

Comment: This is not a bad idea in and of itself. It is a programming language, but to be a sensible DSL, it must stay specific to the domain. ie don't use you central heating system control language to solve sudoku.

Answer (score 0):

Let him write the regulation part in pseudo code or text, and you implement it yourself. It's easier and much less error-prone than your method.

Comment: He would like to learn programming. When the problem arises with regulation process, we both need good understanding of this function. And it even looks more informative to me also...

Comment: @user2152780 - If he would like to learn programming, why not simply teach him then? (Or find a good tutorial for him) C isn't a complicated language like C++. With a few lessons and a bit of practice, he could write that code without any trickery at all. And still have a better understanding of what's going on.

Comment: @Vilx If a DSL is the real aim, then complexity is not the issue, generality is.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - It's a DSL written for a single person. So the question becomes - is it easier to write a brand-spanking-new DSL and teach it to the target person; or just teach the person C in the first place. Especially if the person is willing to learn programming anyway. DSLs created for the purpose of describing business rules tend to become quite general themselves. I'm not insisting that it's the case here, but it certainly is a risk, and the "deep nesting" prediction only exacerbates that.

Comment: Got the impression it was two people, in fact to be more correct two roles. Wouldn't argue against phase 1 being an internal dsl though, as in a subset of C.

Answer (score 0):

> make ansi c function programmable for non-programmers using simple if-then-else-clauses?

This is quite confusing. I see two separate possibilities here.

1. The problem itself is so easy that a few simple if-then-else statements will do. You can do the job faster and better than your friend.
2. The problem is not so simple, so just a few if-then-else statements will not be enough. In this case, you will end up creating such a complicated "simplification" of C that it will be faster ad better if you write everything yourself in C in the first place.

---

The reverse is also true. If your friend really wants to get involved, he can work in parallel with you (i.e., duplicate work) so he has a chance to actually learn C. In this way, in the future, he will be able to help you by writing proper C code.